# Embedded TV for displaying live graphs from server

Tags: monitors, embedded-systems, all-in-one

I am looking to set up a system at work to replace our figures board that we hand write each week.

I would like;
50 inch screen,
At least 1080p resolution,
USB and Ethernet connectivity,
Video out (HDMI or Display port etc.),
It must also be wall mountable.

Ideally I have a budget of £1000 but can be a bit flexible. However the cheaper the better.

One display that meets all my needs is the Samsung DM48E/DM55E but this is a bit pricey.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are looking for TV in UK. All TV's I listed below have VESA mount so you can mount them on the wall.

If you are looking for cheapest solution I would recommend this TV's (all of them meet your requirements):

- **LG 50LF652V** - [£537.55 on transparent-uk.com](http://transparent-uk.com/lg-50lf652v-50-full-hd-3d-compatibility-smart-tv-wi-fi-black-led-tv.html)
- **Philips 50PFH5300** - [£440.33 on www.lambda-tek.com](http://www.lambda-tek.com/Philips-50PFH5300~sh/B2389752&viewOverview=y#product-view)
- **LG 50LF5800** - [£439.08 on www.lambda-tek.com](http://www.lambda-tek.com/LG-50LF5800~sh/B2827314&origin=skinflint30.9)